# $X,Y,Z$ geometric. $P(X \le Y \le Z)$?

Tags: probability

I have a math problem concerning geometric distributions. I've seen some solutions to similar problems online but they concerned continuous distributions.

In my case, I have three independent random variables $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ with geometric distributions, such that $P(X=k) =  \frac{7}{8} \left( \frac{1}{8} \right)^{k-1}$, $P(Y=k) =  \frac{3}{4} \left( \frac{1}{4} \right)^{k-1}$ and  $P(Z=k) =  \dfrac{1}{2^k}$. For $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ we have $k=1,2,\ldots $

How can I calculate $P\left(X \leq Y \leq Z\right)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(X\leq Y\leq Z)=\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}\bigg(P(X\leq y\leq Z|Y=y)P(Y=y)\bigg)$$

Now given $Y=y$, by independence you have $P(X\leq y\leq Z|Y=y)=P(X\leq y,Z\geq y)=P(X\leq y)P(Z\geq y)$

So $$P(X\leq Y\leq Z)=\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}\sum_{r=0}^{y}\sum_{m=y}^{\infty}\frac{3}{4}(\frac{1}{4})^{y}\cdot\frac{7}{8}(\frac{1}{8})^{r}\cdot\frac{1}{2^{m}}$$

Now it's a matter of applying formulas for the geometric sum (both finite and infinite)

$$=\frac{3\cdot 7}{4\cdot 8}+\frac{3}{4}\sum_{y=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^{y}}\bigg(\frac{1-\frac{1}{8^{y+1}}}{2^{y}}\bigg)$$ .

Comment: Thanks very much! Although I believe there's a small mistake in the formula for P(X<=Y<=Z): Instead of (1/4)^y and (1/8)^r, it should be (1/4)^(y-1) and (1/8)^(r-1), as given in my question. Having calculated it that way, I got the right answer.

Comment: Ah I see. Well there are two conventions to take Geometric random variables. One assumes that it takes values in $\Bbb{N}$ and the other in $\Bbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ . I subconciously chose the latter convention.  Well in any case , if you apply the relevant formulas correctly (as you did) then you'll arrive at the required result. What's important  is to remember the technique I used. I conditioned on the middle one and took expectaion. Anyways, I'm glad you figured it out.